# double boot on the same PI

Tags: boot, retropie

I have a pi for 2usages:

- retropi
- watch video from netflix into the pi-linux (standard)

Today the pi boots with retropi interface direclty and if i want to watch videos i have to quit emulationstation and startx.
Is there a way to have a boot menu with first option boot retropi and the second option startx directly...?
Thanks

Comment: Have you searched for a solution first? Please do that! https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Then install `retroarch` in raspbian and use it. Then you can have both.

Comment: i want a boot menu...if possible....

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly that with NOOBS. I have mine on a 32 GB card dual booting to a Raspian desktop or RetroPi with the option to select at boot. It will boot to the last used one after a certain time. I'm not sure if you can disable that or extend the time, my guess is probably.

Also, I'm assuming that by "pi-linux (standard)" you mean the default Raspian OS.

[Noobs Link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/)

Comment: NOOBS has been discontinued. Use PINN.